# VBA User Form Lookup returning blank values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problem with a user form returning lookup values in a textbox based on the value from a drop-down list within the form.  If I select an item from a list, taken from a table within the workbook, I would like a textbox in the same form to return the reference number for the item selected.

I'm using the following code:

```
With TestNameFuntionBox

Dim rngOWASPControls As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("List")

For Each rngOWASPControls In ws.Range("A2:D80")
Me.TestNameFunctionBox.AddItem rngOWASPControls.Value

Next rngOWASPControls

End With
```

It seems as though whilst the drop-down list is available in the form to select, the value returned is not being picked up for the lookup as the lookup textbox remains blank.

I've tried to enter one entry which exists in the table such as the following:

```
TestNameValueFunctionBox.Value = "Review Webserver"
```

The Lookup textbox works absolutely fine and populates the value required.  I'm using the following VBA code for the reference textbox:

```
With OWASPRefBox

    If TestNameValueFunctionBox.Value <> "" Then
        OWASPRefBox.Value =   Application.VLookup(TestNameValueFunctionBox.value, Worksheets("List").Range("A2:D80"), 3, FALSE)
    End If

End With
```

I hope I've explained it well enough!

Comment: Your question isn't clear - you need to include the subroutine headers here, I'm guessing your first procedure is an `Initialize()` event and the second is a `Change()` event? These are crucial to your question. Also, you have `TestNameFunctionBox` in your first procedure, but then you use `TestNameValueFunctionBox` in your second - are these two different boxes? Also, you're loading your drop-down list with values from columns B, C, and D, which are irrelevant to your `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: My guess would be that the last code snippet you post is not running when the user selects an item.  You need to call it from an event handler (e.g. `AfterUpdate`) on the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With TestNameFuntionBox

        Dim rngOWASPControls As Range
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Worksheets("List")

        For Each rngOWASPControls In ws.Range("A2:A80")
            If rngOWASPControls <> "" Then
                Me.TestNameFunctionBox.AddItem rngOWASPControls.Value
            End If
        Next rngOWASPControls

    End With

End Sub
Private Sub TestNameFunctionBox_Change()

    If TestNameFunctionBox.Value <> "" Then
        OWASPRefBox.Value = Application.VLookup(TestNameFunctionBox.Value, Worksheets("List").Range("A2:D80"), 3, False)
    End If

End Sub
```

Sample Data:

[image: img1]

Userform at initialize:

[image: img2]

Selecting "Cat" returns the value in column 3:

[image: img3]

Comment: Hi, Thank you, that worked great!  I've tested it and realised the reason why it did not work the first time was that I did not separate out the procedures.  If I wanted to also lookup a second and third value e.g. category and domain, would I need a separate procedure to get this to work?

Comment: I managed to get it to work for extra fields too, added under the second function.